# Query on line intersection

Tags: qgis-3, intersection

I have used the line intersection tool in QGIS 3 and I have used vector id for example: vector 1 intersects with 3 and the point (id 1) but also repeats the same imformation in reverse saying vector 3 intersects with vector 1 and then gives another point (id 2).

Is there a way of deleting or sorting the attribute table so the information is not repeated?

Comment: Have you tried **Delete duplicate geometries** tool on the `Intersection` point layer, derived from `Line intersection` tool?

Comment: I didnt thank you. It was exactly what i was looking for

Comment: I'm glad to be of help :)